# How do we know that every function of a DE we "solved" satifies the equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a D.E.  $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y,x)$, which we solve by taking functions of both sides, dividing integrateing etc.

How do we know that every function of a  DE we solved satifies the equation? And how do we know that we found all solutions?

For example, suppose we use some function on both sides which is not bijective on the range of expression then we surley loose some solution right? How would one keep track of which solutions one looses or even introduce using different kinds of operations?

Comment: This is the reason for uniqueness and existence theorems, which state the exact conditions for a DE to have the solution that is found. Picard–Lindelöf is one such example.

Comment: @DaveNine that only applies to IVP. And what if I take the sqaure of both sides and then end up loosing the solution which is related to the IVP I am looking for? What do I do then?

Comment: Well, in that case you'd want to make sure that both your equation and initial value are satisfied, that completely decides which sign to take in the solution. P-L naturally applied the 'initial value', but you don't have to name it, you could just have $y(x_0)$ sitting around without giving it a symbol, it occurs naturally in the theorem either way.

Comment: @DaveNine well I was more concerned about which solutions from a parametrised family that we loose and how to think to keep track of them. Which ones gets lost etc.

Comment: If you have those concerns, why not give your original post a little more information? It's usually better than such a broad question.

Comment: @DaveNine It hard writing good questions. One has to convey everything and yet not say to much to make it confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ODEs it's as with all equations or systems of equations: An "equation" (or system, incl. extra conditions, etc.)  $\Phi(x)=0$ defined for elements $x$ in some base set $X$  *implicitly* defines a *solution set*
$$S:=\bigl\{x\in X\,\bigm|\,\Phi(x)=0\bigr\}\subset X\ .$$
It follows that for any $x\in X$ it is easy to test whether $x\in S$; but we do not have an a priori overview over $S$. The task is to obtain an *explicit* presentation of $S$ in the form of a finite list $S=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_r\}$, or a parametric representation which produces all elements of $S$ in a bijective way.

Confronted with a "new" ODE one usually applies the procedures you describe in the form of a chain
$$\Phi(x)=0\quad\Rightarrow\ldots\Rightarrow\ldots\quad\Rightarrow x\in Q\ ,\tag{1}$$
where now $Q$ is an explicitly given set of functions, say the set $y(t)=Ce^t$, where $C\in{\mathbb R}$ is arbitrary. But herewith we only have proven $S\subset Q$, and now have to test for each $x\in Q$ whether it is actually a solution to the original equation. By the way: There may also be a small leak in the chain $(1)$, and we have lost some special solutions which then do not appear in $Q$. As an example consider the ODE $x'=x^{2/3}$ where the special solution $x(t)\equiv0$ tends to get lost in the usual procedure.

It is a different matter if your ODE is of a type for which you have a general theory that guarantees "a three-dimensional vector space of solutions" or "exactly one solution". An example: The ODE $x'''-2x''+x=0$ is a linear homogeneous equation of third order. The theory says that the solution set $S$ is a vector space of dimension $3$. If you find, by whichever means, three linearly independent solutions $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ then you can say right away that the general solution is given by $t\mapsto C_1x_1(t)+\ldots+C_3x_3(t)$. Similarly in the case of an IVP satisfying the regulatory assumptions. If in the course of doing $(1)$ you obtain $Q=\{x_*\}$, then you can say that $x_*$ is *the* solution of the given IVP without performing further tests.

Comment: Right, not every $x \in Q$ is a solution(i.e we might add solutions) and we might also loose some solution. Is it even possible to keep track of whats happening? i.e if we really consider the implications of the operations (theoretically speaking).

Comment: @mathgeeek: There is no algorithm, valid in all situations. Work diligently. Collect experiences.

Comment: Is the implications in $(1)$ necessarily implications? dosnt "bijective" operations (invertible function space operators) correspond to equivalence? which if we can find would give us the set $S$ and nothing more?

Comment: @user1: Of course some of the $\Rightarrow$s in $(1)$ could be $\Leftrightarrow$s. If all of them are then you have proven $S=Q$ "in one sweep".

Comment: ok, and is my suggestion of that the operation one preforms has a corresponding operator that is invertible on the function space sufficient to have equivalence?

Comment: @user1: I suggest you formulate a new question where you describe more precisely what you have in mind.

Comment: Your last statement "Similarly in the case of an IVP satisfying the regulatory assumptions..." confuses me a little. We still need to check weather it is a solution right? We still only know $S \subset Q$. Knowing there is a solution wont take us further in this sense imo